# Image processing on browser

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.x, rest

I need to do some image processing on a browser where I upload images and with my python script, it manipulates the images. In the end, I just want to open an HTML page where I can simply use buttons there to process my python script. Please tell me how can I do it? I don't know much about web development. I don't need to host a website. I just want to do it locally so that if I give my files to anyone they can access it by just opening the HTML document.

Comment: But .. but isn't Python a server-side language?

Comment: You need to host a website if you want to run python. you can host it on local also and other user can access it with your ip over your network.

Comment: What about django? Should I use it?

Comment: You should learn a bit about _client-server_ architecture. Python (or php, etc) are _server side_ languages. Html, javascript, css are _client side_ (browsers) languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to practice and you need to upload an image and processing in your web app you need to use Phyton(with Django should be more fast to create what you want) and MySQL(or another database) to save the data.